Go doesn't install correctly, paths aren't added as environment variables, no language server
Most languages I install, I just install it in Windows, install the VSCode extension and it works.
Go doesn't seem to do that.
I install go using these instructions https://go.dev/doc/install, then I run go mod init, then add some code, and it immediately starts showing the following error.
Failed to run 'C:\Program Files\Go\bin\go.exe env. The config change may not be applied correctly.
I didn't make any config changes, I just installed the darn thing.
The steps in here didn't work: https://go.dev/wiki/SettingGOPATH
Not really a vote of confidence when the language installs broken.
Has anyone run into this before, can they explain why, and how do I fix it?
Thanks!

Can you run the command manually?  If it fails, the error might give you some more useful information.

@StephenNewell I uninstalled it, and I tried to remove every last trace of it from my computer. I'll try on a different computer. It may be some kind of permissions issue. It's my work computer, which I have admin privileges, but maybe go does something different that's being shut down by our protection software. Thanks for the reply!

So since you successfully run go mod init, your Golang seems working fine. I guess the problem is with your VSCode's Golang extension.
Can you please try this answer and see if it solves your problem?

For some reason, when I did init, it was putting the wrong root in the .mod file. I ended up getting it working. Thank you for your reply.
